# shell - var length with if condition gives error

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, grep

I am trying to see if I found something using grep or not with this

```
found=`grep -F "something" somefile.txt`

if ((${#found} == 0)); then
   echo "Not Found"
else
   echo "Found"
fi
```

I succeeded using above logic that if grep found something it stores the output in `found` variable but the issue I am facing is with `if` condition. Whenever `found=0` it gives me some error like that

> final.sh: 13: final.sh: 0: not found

FYI: `final.sh` is the script name

Comment: use the $? for checking whether found or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether some string is in your file, you can use the return status from grep

```
grep -q something somefile.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

a shorter form will be

```
grep -q something somefile.txt && echo found || echo not found
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're writing bash specific code, but running it with sh. In bash, `(( .. ))` is an arithmetic context, while in POSIX sh, it's merely two nested subshells, causing it to try to execute the number as a command.

You can run it with bash instead of sh by specifying `#!/bin/bash` in the shebang, and/or using `bash yourfile` instead of `sh yourfile` if you invoke it that way.

The correct way for your example, however, is to use `grep`'s exit status directly:

```
if grep -q something somefile
then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
found=$(grep -F "something" somefile.txt)
if [ $? = 0 ]; then # $? is the return status of a previous command. Grep will return 0 if it found something, and 1 if nothing was found.
    echo "Something was found. Found=$found"
else
    echo 'Nothing was found'
fi
```

I find this code more elegant than other answers.
But anyway, why are you writing in `sh`? Why don't you use `bash`? Are you sure that you need that portability? [Check out this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell) to see if you really need `sh`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do that sort of thing:

```
found=$(grep -F "something" somefile.txt)

if [[ -z $found ]]; then
    echo "Not found"
else
    echo "Found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Stabledog, it gives error `final.sh: 13: final.sh: [[: not found
`

Comment: I guess you're getting parsed by sh instead of bash.   You can remove one of the brackets on each side of the -z test to solve that (sh doesn't have the double-bracket construct).   Or, you can put "#!/bin/bash" at the first line of your script to invoke bash instead of sh.

Comment: Also, note that I prefer "$( )" for evaluating expressions.  You will also see people using "` `" (backticks).   The trouble with backticks is that they can't be nested... I also think they're just harder to spot in the jumble of script tokens.   But some people still use them.